# How to access the generated JavaScript files by Kotlin/JavaScript in KMM project?

Tags: javascript, kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

I successfully added Kotlin JavaScript Target in my Kotlin Mutliplatform Mobile.

I have added the index.html file in jsMain/resources folder and it's being served when running the gradle task jsBrowserDevelopmentRun

But the problem is, I can't add the generated JavaScript file from Kotlin scripts via  tag

The main thing I find frustrating about this is it's unclear what the script src attribute should contain.

If I drop an index.html file in `src/main/resources` (for a KotlinJS browser project), the `index.html` file gets copied into `build/processedResources/Js/main/`,

While my JavaScript gets dropped into `build/js/packages/$project/kotlin/$project.js`.

So I have kind of no idea what the src should be to make things work.

Also, the `build/js/packages/$project/kotlin/$project.js`contains a `index.html`, but it's not served instead of that the `build/processedResources/Js/main/` has being served. But the later don't have JavaScript files

Also, in the build log, I get some messages, which seems to be an issue,

```
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Content not from webpack is served from '/Users/rageshantonyd/AndroidStudioProjects/AllTarg/shared/build/processedResources/js/main' directory
<i> [webpack-dev-middleware] wait until bundle finished: /
```

I would like to do something like,

Serve the index.html in `build/js/packages/$project/kotlin/$project.js`

OR

Copy the entire `build/js/packages/$project/kotlin/$project.js` files to `build/processedResources/Js/main/` after building and then Serve

Note:
I manully did the 2nd method, but now the JS files showing in console

```
Uncaught Error: Error loading module 'AllTarg-shared'. Its dependency 'kotlin-kotlin-stdlib-js-ir' was not found. Please, check whether 'kotlin-kotlin-stdlib-js-ir' is loaded prior to 'AllTarg-shared'.
    at AllTarg-shared.js:8:13
    at AllTarg-shared.js:15:2
```

Refs:
[image: folder that have JS files]

[image: the folder served, no JS files]

Comment: I find it rather strange to put `index.html` in `jsMain/resources`. The index file is served by the server, and should be in the server resources. What server component are you using? Ktor?

Answer (score 0):

If you use builtin server you referring to js file from html as `$project.js` should work, i.e. you need to add to your html something like:

```
<script src="$project.js"></script>
```